# SerializedProperty always null with Unity3D PropertyDrawers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use for the first time Unity3D's [PropertyDrawer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html).

I copied and paste exactly the example found in the [blog](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/09/07/property-drawers-in-unity-4/), but it seems not to work.

Here's a simplified version that still doesn't work:

```
//a serializable class, it should be possible write an custom property drawer for it
[System.Serializable]
public class SimpleClass
{
  public int myField;
}
```

here's an empty drawer that draws nothing:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (SimpleClass))]
public class SimpleClassDrawer : PropertyDrawer{

    public override void OnGUI (Rect pos, SerializedProperty prop, GUIContent label) 
    {
      SerializedProperty myField= prop.FindPropertyRelative ("myField");
      //here's the problem: myField always null
    }
```

and finally a MonoBehavior with a public field of `SimpleClass`:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
  public SimpleClass s;
}
```

The `OnGUI` method of `SimpleClassDrawer` is always called, but `myField` is always null.

I don't understand what I'm missing? Any clue?

EDIT:

After a deeper investigation it seems that `OnGUI` is called **twice**. The second time the property is null and throws a `NullReferenceExceptionw` whenever I try do draw it through
`EditorGUI.PropertyField`.

EDIT2:

The last version of my post containted few copy and paste errors. I tried even using the code posted by Jerdak but the problem remains at least in Unity 4.2. This is the stacktrace:

> NullReferenceException: Curve: SerializedProperty is null
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.BeginProperty (Rect totalPosition,
>   UnityEngine.GUIContent label, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3278)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.SinglePropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3760)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label,
>   Boolean includeChildren) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3694)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3688)
>   PropertyDrawerTest.OnGUI (Rect pos, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty
>   prop, UnityEngine.GUIContent label) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Editor/Core/Pool/ScaledCurveDrawer.cs:14)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.SinglePropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3746)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label,
>   Boolean includeChildren) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3694)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3688)
>   PropertyDrawerTest.OnGUI (Rect pos, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty
>   prop, UnityEngine.GUIContent label) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Editor/Core/Pool/ScaledCurveDrawer.cs:14)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.SinglePropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3746)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label,
>   Boolean includeChildren) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3694)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, Boolean includeChildren) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3683)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUI.PropertyField (Rect position,
>   UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorGUI.cs:3679)
>   UnityEditor.Editor.OptimizedInspectorGUIImplementation (Rect
>   contentRect) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorBindings.cs:189)
>   UnityEditor.GenericInspector.OnOptimizedInspectorGUI (Rect
>   contentRect) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/Mono/Inspector/GenericInspector.cs:46)
>   UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditors (Boolean isRepaintEvent,
>   UnityEditor.Editor[] editors, Boolean eyeDropperDirty) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:864)
>   UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.OnGUI () (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/cac08d8a5e25d4cb/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:266)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at
>   /Applications/buildAgent/work/b59ae78cff80e584/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)

Comment: Try changing `[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (ScaledCurve))]` to `[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (SimpleClass))]` in your SimpleClassDrawer.cs file and maybe changing SimpleClassDrawer to subclass PropertyDrawer?

Comment: According to the example, SimpleClassDrawer needs to extend PropertyDrawer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example, Unity version 4.1.3f3.  I'm not sure if your problems are related to `SimpleClassDrawer` not subclassing `PropertyDrawer` or `CustomPropertyDrawer` using an incorrect type. (as I noted in my comment.)

The property wrapper:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;


[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (ScaledCurve))]
public class PropertyDrawerTest : PropertyDrawer {
public override void OnGUI (Rect pos, SerializedProperty prop, GUIContent label) {
    SerializedProperty myValue = prop.FindPropertyRelative ("myValue");

    int indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 1;
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(
        new Rect(pos.x,pos.y,pos.width,pos.height),
        myValue,
        label
    );
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;
}
}
```

The property I'm wrapping:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class ScaledCurve {
    public int myValue = 1;
}
```

And the class using this property:

```
public class PropertyDrawerImpl : MonoBehaviour {
    public ScaledCurve Curve;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but it was just a copy and paste error. I'm using the last version of unity 4.2 and it seems not to work. Which version are you using?

Comment: Version 4.1.3f3.  [This might](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/192135-Unity-4-2-and-Property-Drawers) be related.

Comment: And confirmed as an issue in version 4.2.0f4.